# Event schedule in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-event

I want to create event in this period (every 2 month  3rd week monday and tuesday) start date="2017-11-01" end date="2019-11-01" in mysql,

i am creating recurring function for task creation like outlook.

example: if i create to do task for electric bill payment in my website with this option (every 2 month  3rd week monday and tuesday)i need notification in that same date for every 2 month once automatically

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: What have you done so far?  What problem are you having? This is very vague, it's impossible to tell you what to do because we don't know what you've got so far, what you do/don't understand or what your actual goal is. Please edit your question to clarify it, otherwise it will probably get closed as being un-answerable.

Comment: now u understand???????

Comment: You've stated your goal, but not what problem you're having. Here we fix problems, we don't give out solutions from nothing with no evidence of any research or coding effort from the person asking the question. Have you written any code yet? If so please show it. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html shows the syntax for creating an event and https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/ has a worked example. This is not something so complicated that you cannot make your own attempt to solve the problem using the existing, freely available guidance.

Comment: thanks....@ ADyson